# Перевод double в string с заданной точностью

Tags: c++

Есть вот такая функция:

```
void DoubleToString(std::string &answer_for_return, double answer) {
    char *convertator = new char;
    sprintf(convertator, "%.7lf", answer);
    answer_for_return = convertator;
    delete convertator;
}
```

Делает, то что мне нужно, но в итоге получается утечка. Задавать сразу размер массива символов нельзя, наверное, ведь вдруг ответ будет слишком большой и не влезет.

Comment: Вы в самом деле боитесь, что потребуется строка больше, скажем, килобайта? (ну, чтоб с бешшшшеным запасом :)). А выделение памяти через `ne` по сравнению с выделением и удалением ее в стеке — весьма дорогостоящая операция...

Answer (score 1):

У вас не утечка, а попытка обращения за пределы доступной памяти. Вы можете сначала определить необходимый размер массива символов с помощью функции [snprintf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf), которая принимает вторым параметром размер массива. Вы можете указать его равным нулю - тогда функция ничего не запишет, но вернёт количество символов, которое требуется для записи (не включая `\0`). Так вы определите, какой размер массива вам нужен. После этого создаёте массив нужной длины и выполняете конвертацию.

Вот пример:

```
void DoubleToString(std::string &answer_for_return, double answer) {
    int count = snprintf(nullptr, 0, "%.7lf", answer);
    if (count > 0)
    {
        char *convertator = new char[count+1];
        sprintf(convertator, "%.7lf", answer);
        answer_for_return = convertator;
        delete convertator;
    }
    
}

int main()
{
    std::string s;
    double a = 3434.33;
    DoubleToString(s, a);
    std::cout << s;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Интересно, ТС реально планирует использовать `"%.70000lf"`, что боится использовать массив заранее заданного размера в стеке, что и куда быстрее, и проще?...

Answer (score 0):

Для преобразования `double` в `string` с заданной точностью можно воспользоваться библиотекой `<sstream>`. Вот пример функции, которая это делает:

```cpp
#include <sstream>

std::string doubleToString(double number, int precision) {
    std::ostringstream stream;
    stream.precision(precision);
    stream << std::fixed << number;
    return stream.str();
}
```

В этой функции мы используем `std::ostringstream` для записи числа в строку с заданной точностью. Метод `precision` устанавливает количество знаков после запятой, а метод `std::fixed` говорит о том, что нужно выводить фиксированную точку. Функция `str()` возвращает полученную строку.

Вы можете использовать эту функцию следующим образом:

```cpp
double value = 3.14159265359;
std::string stringValue = doubleToString(value, 7);
```

В этом примере мы конвертируем число `value` в строку с точностью до 7 знаков после запятой и сохраняем результат в `stringValue`.

---

Конечно, можно использовать `sprintf` для преобразования `double` в `string`. Вот пример функции:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>

std::string doubleToString(double number, int precision) {
    char buffer[50];
    sprintf(buffer, "%.*lf", precision, number);
    return std::string(buffer);
}
```

В этой функции мы используем `sprintf`, который записывает отформатированные данные в буфер символов `buffer`. Мы передаем точность как аргумент в метод `sprintf` и используем `.*` для динамического задания точности. Затем мы конвертируем буфер в объект `std::string` и возвращаем его.

Вы можете использовать эту функцию следующим образом:

```cpp
double value = 3.14159265359;
std::string stringValue = doubleToString(value, 7);
```

В этом примере мы конвертируем число `value` в строку с точностью до 7 знаков после запятой и сохраняем результат в `stringValue`.